# Facebook user deauthorizes the app

Tags: php, facebook

when user accepts the facebook application from my website, I am storing the user details and facebook details(access token) in database.

when he removes my application from facebook i want to remove the detail from database. how to do this?

I can give Deauthorize Callback url. if some one removes application, it will redirect to this page. but, wt should be the code here to delete the data from db? I means, when it redirect, will it post the access token details, so that i can charge fro access token and delete that row.

Comment: It would take no more time to find out than to write the question here. Make a page that emails the contents of $_REQUEST/$_GET/$_POST to you. Make that your callback URL. Authorize then deauthorize yourself. Check email and you'll know exactly what data you have available.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's clearly stated in the [authentication document](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/):

> **App Deauthorization**
>
> When a user of your app removes it in
>   the App Dashboard or blocks the app in
>   the News Feed, your app can be
>   notified by specifying a Deauthorize
>   Callback URL in the Developer App.
>   During app removal we will send an
>   HTTP POST request containing a single
>   parameter, signed_request, which
>   contains the user id (UID) of the user
>   that just removed your app. You will
>   not receive an user access token in
>   this request and all existing user
>   access tokens will be automatically
>   expired.

So using the [`signed_request`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) function on its own docuement:

```
<?php
function parse_signed_request($signed_request, $secret) {
  list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 

  // decode the data
  $sig = base64_url_decode($encoded_sig);
  $data = json_decode(base64_url_decode($payload), true);

  if (strtoupper($data['algorithm']) !== 'HMAC-SHA256') {
    error_log('Unknown algorithm. Expected HMAC-SHA256');
    return null;
  }

  // check sig
  $expected_sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $secret, $raw = true);
  if ($sig !== $expected_sig) {
    error_log('Bad Signed JSON signature!');
    return null;
  }

  return $data;
}

function base64_url_decode($input) {
  return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_', '+/'));
}

$result = parse_signed_request($_REQUEST['signed_request'],"APP_SECRET");


$myFile = "deauthorize.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, $result["user_id"] . "\n");
fclose($fh);

?>
```

So all you need to do is get the `$result["user_id"]` query your DB and remove the record.

P.S: I would recommend adding a new field called `active` and just deactivate the user instead of removing the record all together.

**EDIT:**
Facebook will NOT redirect the user to the deauthorize URL! it'll ping it only:

> Facebook pings this URL when a user
>   deauthorizes your app

Comment: This is exactly what is needed. Don't forget to replace APP_SECRET with your actual app_secret.

Answer (score 0):

This code is not working, although it gets called when a user deauthorizes the app the only data passed into the function is a "1" (Tested with test user and my own FB account when app is live)

file_put_contents("test.txt",$fbUserId . " ". print_r($_REQUEST['signed_request']));

in test.txt file " 1"