# Deauthorize Callback user_id is 0

Tags: php, facebook, callback

when a user delete the app the user_id in the signed_request is 0...

Here is the array:

```
Array
(
    [algorithm] => HMAC-SHA256
    [issued_at] => 1302690240
    [user] => Array
        (
            [country] => de
            [locale] => de_DE
        )

    [user_id] => 0
)
```

I've tried this with two facebook accounts. This is my test code:

```
require "lib/facebook/facebook.php";

$FACEBOOK = new Facebook(array(
            'appId'  => '123',
            'secret' => '123',
            'cookie' => true,
        ));
$logfile = fopen('fb.log', 'a+');
fwrite ($logfile,print_r($_REQUEST,true). print_r($FACEBOOK->getSignedRequest(),true));
fclose ($logfile);
```

The "Requests 2.0" in the app settings is activated!

is something wrong in the code? Can anybody help my?

greetings!

Comment: Would [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859820/facebook-user-deauthorizes-the-app/4860829#4860829) help?

Comment: Thanks, i know this link. the function parse_signed_request is now build in into the facebook class, but i tied it also and the result is the same.

Comment: Any progress with this? I'm getting the exact same thing - in Python :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a bug from facebook. Other peoples have the same problem.

i created a facebook bug ticket!

http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=16733