# Using coldfusion (facebook-cf-sdk), I'd like to mark a user's record in my DB whenever a user deauthorizes

Tags: facebook, coldfusion

I found this example using php, [Facebook user deauthorizes the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859820/facebook-user-deauthorizes-the-app) but unfortunately, I kinda suck at coding and am not sure how to make the conversion to coldfusion. Thanks!

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)? Take a stab at it first. Use [the PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/) to find the purpose of the various functions like [`explode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php). Then use the CF equivalent, like `listToArray`. Post back if you run into problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so after a major Derp moment, I realized that the [facebook-cf-sdk framework](http://facebooksdk.riaforge.org/) already handles the FB signed request. I simply needed to get the userid by doing the following:

```
if (APP_ID is "" or SECRET_KEY is "") {
// App not configured
facebookGraphAPI = new FacebookGraphAPI();
} else {
// Create facebookApp instance
facebookApp = new FacebookApp(appId=YOUR_APP_ID, secretKey=YOUR_SECRET_KEY);

// See if there is a user from a cookie or session
userId = facebookApp.getUserId();
```

Thanks Leigh for the kick in the butt ;-)

Comment: Good work :) .. and thanks for posting the resolution.