# Facebook Notification to Users Interrupt When It Tries to Send To a User Who has not Installed Our App

Tags: php, facebook, error-handling, notifications

We get the error below when we try to send to a user who has uninstalled our app. The error is OK, but we need to continue to send notifications after getting the error.

Any ideas about hot to make it continue?

```
Message: Hello World
Test Users: 589069632 (uninstalled the app),594917560 (installed the app-he should get the message)
```

**Error Code**

```
FacebookApiException Object
(
[result:protected] => Array
    (
        [error] => Array
            (
                [message] => (#200) Cannot send notifications to a user who has not installed the app
                [type] => OAuthException
                [code] => 200
            )

    )

[message:protected] => (#200) Cannot send notifications to a user who has not installed the app
[string:Exception:private] => 
[code:protected] => 0
[file:protected] => /home/hurremlekahvefali.com/domains/app.hurremlekahvefali.com/httpdocs/hurrem/facebook/base_facebook.php
[line:protected] => 1238
[trace:Exception:private] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [file] => /home/hurremlekahvefali.com/domains/app.hurremlekahvefali.com/httpdocs/hurrem/facebook/base_facebook.php
                [line] => 870
                [function] => throwAPIException
                [class] => BaseFacebook
                [type] => ->
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [error] => Array
                                    (
                                        [message] => (#200) Cannot send notifications to a user who has not installed the app
                                        [type] => OAuthException
                                        [code] => 200
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [function] => _graph
                [class] => BaseFacebook
                [type] => ->
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => /589069632/notifications
                        [1] => POST
                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [access_token] => 490863990938333|cc281af73699bd0d928672362bd05452
                                [href] => 
                                [template] => Hello World
                            )

                    )

            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [file] => /home/hurremlekahvefali.com/domains/app.hurremlekahvefali.com/httpdocs/hurrem/facebook/base_facebook.php
                [line] => 644
                [function] => call_user_func_array
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Facebook Object
                                    (
                                        [sharedSessionID:protected] => 
                                        [appId:protected] => 490863990938333
                                        [appSecret:protected] => cc281af73699bd0d928672362bd05452
                                        [user:protected] => 
                                        [signedRequest:protected] => 
                                        [state:protected] => 
                                        [accessToken:protected] => 
                                        [fileUploadSupport:protected] => 
                                        [trustForwarded:protected] => 
                                    )

                                [1] => _graph
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => /589069632/notifications
                                [1] => POST
                                [2] => Array
                                    (
                                        [access_token] => 490863990938333|cc281af73699bd0d928672362bd05452
                                        [href] => 
                                        [template] => Hello World
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [file] => /home/hurremlekahvefali.com/domains/app.hurremlekahvefali.com/httpdocs/hurrem/modules/backend/notification_send.php
                [line] => 65
                [function] => api
                [class] => BaseFacebook
                [type] => ->
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => /589069632/notifications
                        [1] => POST
                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [access_token] => 490863990938333|cc281af73699bd0d928672362bd05452
                                [href] => 
                                [template] => Hello World
                            )

                    )

            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [file] => /home/hurremlekahvefali.com/domains/app.hurremlekahvefali.com/httpdocs/hurrem/modules/backend/notification_send.php
                [line] => 48
                [function] => sender
                [args] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [file] => /home/hurremlekahvefali.com/domains/app.hurremlekahvefali.com/httpdocs/hurrem/lib/BaseController.php
                [line] => 52
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => /home/hurremlekahvefali.com/domains/app.hurremlekahvefali.com/httpdocs/hurrem/modules/backend/notification_send.php
                    )

                [function] => include
            )

        [6] => Array
            (
                [file] => /home/hurremlekahvefali.com/domains/app.hurremlekahvefali.com/httpdocs/hurrem/lib/BaseController.php
                [line] => 22
                [function] => setTemplate
                [class] => BaseController
                [type] => ->
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => backend
                        [1] => notification_send
                        [2] => Request Object
                            (
                                [method:protected] => POST
                                [queryString:protected] => 
                                [facebookID] => 589069632,594917560
                                [notification_app_link] => 
                                [notification_message] => Hello World
                            )

                    )

            )

        [7] => Array
            (
                [file] => /home/hurremlekahvefali.com/domains/app.hurremlekahvefali.com/httpdocs/hurrem/index.php
                [line] => 72
                [function] => dispatch
                [class] => BaseController
                [type] => ->
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => backend
                        [1] => notification_send
                        [2] => Request Object
                            (
                                [method:protected] => POST
                                [queryString:protected] => 
                                [facebookID] => 589069632,594917560
                                [notification_app_link] => 
                                [notification_message] => Hello World
                            )

                    )

            )

    )

[previous:Exception:private] => 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

An exception will be thrown if you try to post to a user who has uninstalled your app.

You should catch the exception and mark the user as uninstalled in your database.

That won't help with continuing the notifications, however.

Three best practices you should be doing:

- Personalising notifications per user, and thus sending individual requests instead of sending the same notification to everyone; one request throwing an exception won't be a problem.
- Batch those individual requests together using the Batch API.
- Using Facebook's deauthorized callback to mark a user disabled when they uninstall your app.

There's a good answer here on how to manage deauthorizations: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4860829/504088