# How to revoke a given Facebook token?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm using OAuth authentication to obtain a token from a Facebook user. My application edits - among other stuff - their Facebook pages. With that token I obtain a permanent token.

The user can unlink its Facebook account from my app. When a user does so, I like to invalidate the token and remove my app from the users apps. It this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0#revoking You can use

```
DELETE /{user-id}/permissions
```

to revoke a user's login to your app.

Furthermore, there's a section in the app's -> settings -> advanced screen where you can specify a so-called "Deauthorize Callback URL". This URL will be called by Facebook if a user actively disconnects your app from his profile settings. Unfortunately I can't find any docs on Facebook concerning this anymore. But there's a question about that here on SO: [Facebook user deauthorizes the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859820/facebook-user-deauthorizes-the-app)

Comment: If my app revokes all the permissions, my app will be removed from the users profile?

Comment: It tested this just now with one of my apps, and it seems to remove the app from the profile correctly

Answer (score 1):

@tobi solution didn't work for me, I had to pass the access token.

```
DELETE /{user-id}/permissions?access_token={access_token}
```

Comment: You have to send the `access_token` somewhere, either as a parameter or set in the header `Authorization Bearer <access_token>`